# The virtual keyboard shifts all my content up the same distance, and some text fields are not visible when I type (Android)

Tags: react-native

I am trying not to put the virtual keyboard above the keyboard, for the last fields it works, but for the first fields, it moves them all up to the point that is not seen when typing.  I am using native base

Look at the gif to understand.

[image]

this is my code

```
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">
      <ScrollView>
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel error={validateForm()}>
            <Label>Correo</Label>
            <Input onChange={e => handldeOnChange("email", e)} />
            <Icon active name="person" style={STYLES.colorIcon} />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel error={validateForm()}>
            <Label>Contraseña</Label>
            <Icon active name="lock" style={STYLES.colorIcon} />
            <Input
              onChange={e => handldeOnChange("password", e)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel error={validateForm()}>
            <Label>Contraseña</Label>
            <Icon active name="lock" style={STYLES.colorIcon} />
            <Input
              onChange={e => handldeOnChange("password", e)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel error={validateForm()}>
            <Label>Contraseña</Label>
            <Icon active name="lock" style={STYLES.colorIcon} />
            <Input
              onChange={e => handldeOnChange("password", e)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel error={validateForm()}>
            <Label>Contraseña</Label>
            <Icon active name="lock" style={STYLES.colorIcon} />
            <Input
              onChange={e => handldeOnChange("password", e)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel error={validateForm()}>
            <Label>Contraseña</Label>
            <Icon active name="lock" style={STYLES.colorIcon} />
            <Input
              onChange={e => handldeOnChange("password", e)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel error={validateForm()}>
            <Label>Contraseña</Label>
            <Icon active name="lock" style={STYLES.colorIcon} />
            <Input
              onChange={e => handldeOnChange("password", e)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
          </Item>
          <Item floatingLabel error={validateForm()}>
            <Label>Contraseña</Label>
            <Icon active name="lock" style={STYLES.colorIcon} />
            <Input
              onChange={e => handldeOnChange("password", e)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
          </Item>
          <Button
            block
            button
            style={styles.buttonLogin}
            onPress={() => handlerLogin()}
            disabled={validateForm()}
          >
            <Text>Ingresar</Text>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  containerLogin: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 40
  },
  buttonLogin: {
    marginTop: 30
  }
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put keyboard item like this:

`<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled>`

Comment: And if you remove KeyboardAvoidingView? won't see the rest but I think you will see the selected item don't?

Comment: I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53626679/8898886